# Converting a random number generator from matlab to C

Tags: c, matlab, random, matlab-deployment, mersenne-twister

I have written some come involving random numbers in matlab. When I run the program in matlab it works fine, giving me different random numbers each time the program is run.

I decided to use matlabs C code generating features to turn the code I had written in matlab to C. In the original matlab function, I used the in-built randn() function to generate the random numbers. I then used matlab's ability to automatically generate C code from a matlab function to turn this code into C. To generate random numbers, the automatically generated C code uses the following algorithm exactly as shown at the bottom of this post.

My code then simply calls the randn() function. However, each time I run the code, the random numbers generated are the same. What can I do to avoid it?

```
    /*
 * randn.c
 *
 * Code generation for function 'randn'
 *
 * C source code generated on: Fri Aug  2 13:33:45 2013
 *
 */

/* Include files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "CondorExitTimeLocation.h"
#include "randn.h"
#include "CondorExitTimeLocation_data.h"

/* Type Definitions */

/* Named Constants */

/* Variable Declarations */

/* Variable Definitions */

/* Function Declarations */
static real_T eml_rand_mt19937ar_stateful(void);
static void genrand_uint32_vector(uint32_T mt[625], uint32_T u[2]);
static real_T genrandu(uint32_T mt[625]);

/* Function Definitions */
static real_T eml_rand_mt19937ar_stateful(void)
{
  real_T r;
  int32_T exitg1;
  uint32_T u32[2];
  int32_T i;
  static const real_T dv0[257] = { 0.0, 0.215241895984875, 0.286174591792068,
    0.335737519214422, 0.375121332878378, 0.408389134611989, 0.43751840220787,
    0.46363433679088, 0.487443966139235, 0.50942332960209, 0.529909720661557,
    0.549151702327164, 0.567338257053817, 0.584616766106378, 0.601104617755991,
    0.61689699000775, 0.63207223638606, 0.646695714894993, 0.660822574244419,
    0.674499822837293, 0.687767892795788, 0.700661841106814, 0.713212285190975,
    0.725446140909999, 0.737387211434295, 0.749056662017815, 0.760473406430107,
    0.771654424224568, 0.782615023307232, 0.793369058840623, 0.80392911698997,
    0.814306670135215, 0.824512208752291, 0.834555354086381, 0.844444954909153,
    0.854189171008163, 0.863795545553308, 0.87327106808886, 0.882622229585165,
    0.891855070732941, 0.900975224461221, 0.909987953496718, 0.91889818364959,
    0.927710533401999, 0.936429340286575, 0.945058684468165, 0.953602409881086,
    0.96206414322304, 0.970447311064224, 0.978755155294224, 0.986990747099062,
    0.99515699963509, 1.00325667954467, 1.01129241744, 1.01926671746548,
    1.02718196603564, 1.03504043983344, 1.04284431314415, 1.05059566459093,
    1.05829648333067, 1.06594867476212, 1.07355406579244, 1.0811144097034,
    1.08863139065398, 1.09610662785202, 1.10354167942464, 1.11093804601357,
    1.11829717411934, 1.12562045921553, 1.13290924865253, 1.14016484436815,
    1.14738850542085, 1.15458145035993, 1.16174485944561, 1.16887987673083,
    1.17598761201545, 1.18306914268269, 1.19012551542669, 1.19715774787944,
    1.20416683014438, 1.2111537262437, 1.21811937548548, 1.22506469375653,
    1.23199057474614, 1.23889789110569, 1.24578749554863, 1.2526602218949,
    1.25951688606371, 1.26635828701823, 1.27318520766536, 1.27999841571382,
    1.28679866449324, 1.29358669373695, 1.30036323033084, 1.30712898903073,
    1.31388467315022, 1.32063097522106, 1.32736857762793, 1.33409815321936,
    1.3408203658964, 1.34753587118059, 1.35424531676263, 1.36094934303328,
    1.36764858359748, 1.37434366577317, 1.38103521107586, 1.38772383568998,
    1.39441015092814, 1.40109476367925, 1.4077782768464, 1.41446128977547,
    1.42114439867531, 1.42782819703026, 1.43451327600589, 1.44120022484872,
    1.44788963128058, 1.45458208188841, 1.46127816251028, 1.46797845861808,
    1.47468355569786, 1.48139403962819, 1.48811049705745, 1.49483351578049,
    1.50156368511546, 1.50830159628131, 1.51504784277671, 1.521803020761,
    1.52856772943771, 1.53534257144151, 1.542128153229, 1.54892508547417,
    1.55573398346918, 1.56255546753104, 1.56939016341512, 1.57623870273591,
    1.58310172339603, 1.58997987002419, 1.59687379442279, 1.60378415602609,
    1.61071162236983, 1.61765686957301, 1.62462058283303, 1.63160345693487,
    1.63860619677555, 1.64562951790478, 1.65267414708306, 1.65974082285818,
    1.66683029616166, 1.67394333092612, 1.68108070472517, 1.68824320943719,
    1.69543165193456, 1.70264685479992, 1.7098896570713, 1.71716091501782,
    1.72446150294804, 1.73179231405296, 1.73915426128591, 1.74654827828172,
    1.75397532031767, 1.76143636531891, 1.76893241491127, 1.77646449552452,
    1.78403365954944, 1.79164098655216, 1.79928758454972, 1.80697459135082,
    1.81470317596628, 1.82247454009388, 1.83028991968276, 1.83815058658281,
    1.84605785028518, 1.8540130597602, 1.86201760539967, 1.87007292107127,
    1.878180486293, 1.88634182853678, 1.8945585256707, 1.90283220855043,
    1.91116456377125, 1.91955733659319, 1.92801233405266, 1.93653142827569,
    1.94511656000868, 1.95376974238465, 1.96249306494436, 1.97128869793366,
    1.98015889690048, 1.98910600761744, 1.99813247135842, 2.00724083056053,
    2.0164337349062, 2.02571394786385, 2.03508435372962, 2.04454796521753,
    2.05410793165065, 2.06376754781173, 2.07353026351874, 2.0833996939983,
    2.09337963113879, 2.10347405571488, 2.11368715068665, 2.12402331568952,
    2.13448718284602, 2.14508363404789, 2.15581781987674, 2.16669518035431,
    2.17772146774029, 2.18890277162636, 2.20024554661128, 2.21175664288416,
    2.22344334009251, 2.23531338492992, 2.24737503294739, 2.25963709517379,
    2.27210899022838, 2.28480080272449, 2.29772334890286, 2.31088825060137,
    2.32430801887113, 2.33799614879653, 2.35196722737914, 2.36623705671729,
    2.38082279517208, 2.39574311978193, 2.41101841390112, 2.42667098493715,
    2.44272531820036, 2.4592083743347, 2.47614993967052, 2.49358304127105,
    2.51154444162669, 2.53007523215985, 2.54922155032478, 2.56903545268184,
    2.58957598670829, 2.61091051848882, 2.63311639363158, 2.65628303757674,
    2.68051464328574, 2.70593365612306, 2.73268535904401, 2.76094400527999,
    2.79092117400193, 2.82287739682644, 2.85713873087322, 2.89412105361341,
    2.93436686720889, 2.97860327988184, 3.02783779176959, 3.08352613200214,
    3.147889289518, 3.2245750520478, 3.32024473383983, 3.44927829856143,
    3.65415288536101, 3.91075795952492 };

  real_T u;
  static const real_T dv1[257] = { 1.0, 0.977101701267673, 0.959879091800108,
    0.9451989534423, 0.932060075959231, 0.919991505039348, 0.908726440052131,
    0.898095921898344, 0.887984660755834, 0.878309655808918, 0.869008688036857,
    0.860033621196332, 0.851346258458678, 0.842915653112205, 0.834716292986884,
    0.826726833946222, 0.818929191603703, 0.811307874312656, 0.803849483170964,
    0.796542330422959, 0.789376143566025, 0.782341832654803, 0.775431304981187,
    0.768637315798486, 0.761953346836795, 0.755373506507096, 0.748892447219157,
    0.742505296340151, 0.736207598126863, 0.729995264561476, 0.72386453346863,
    0.717811932630722, 0.711834248878248, 0.705928501332754, 0.700091918136512,
    0.694321916126117, 0.688616083004672, 0.682972161644995, 0.677388036218774,
    0.671861719897082, 0.66639134390875, 0.660975147776663, 0.655611470579697,
    0.650298743110817, 0.645035480820822, 0.639820277453057, 0.634651799287624,
    0.629528779924837, 0.624450015547027, 0.619414360605834, 0.614420723888914,
    0.609468064925773, 0.604555390697468, 0.599681752619125, 0.594846243767987,
    0.590047996332826, 0.585286179263371, 0.580559996100791, 0.575868682972354,
    0.571211506735253, 0.566587763256165, 0.561996775814525, 0.557437893618766,
    0.552910490425833, 0.548413963255266, 0.543947731190026, 0.539511234256952,
    0.535103932380458, 0.530725304403662, 0.526374847171684, 0.522052074672322,
    0.517756517229756, 0.513487720747327, 0.509245245995748, 0.505028667943468,
    0.500837575126149, 0.49667156905249, 0.492530263643869, 0.488413284705458,
    0.484320269426683, 0.480250865909047, 0.476204732719506, 0.47218153846773,
    0.468180961405694, 0.464202689048174, 0.460246417812843, 0.456311852678716,
    0.452398706861849, 0.448506701507203, 0.444635565395739, 0.440785034665804,
    0.436954852547985, 0.433144769112652, 0.429354541029442, 0.425583931338022,
    0.421832709229496, 0.418100649837848, 0.414387534040891, 0.410693148270188,
    0.407017284329473, 0.403359739221114, 0.399720314980197, 0.396098818515832,
    0.392495061459315, 0.388908860018789, 0.385340034840077, 0.381788410873393,
    0.378253817245619, 0.374736087137891, 0.371235057668239, 0.367750569779032,
    0.364282468129004, 0.360830600989648, 0.357394820145781, 0.353974980800077,
    0.350570941481406, 0.347182563956794, 0.343809713146851, 0.340452257044522,
    0.337110066637006, 0.333783015830718, 0.330470981379163, 0.327173842813601,
    0.323891482376391, 0.320623784956905, 0.317370638029914, 0.314131931596337,
    0.310907558126286, 0.307697412504292, 0.30450139197665, 0.301319396100803,
    0.298151326696685, 0.294997087799962, 0.291856585617095, 0.288729728482183,
    0.285616426815502, 0.282516593083708, 0.279430141761638, 0.276356989295668,
    0.273297054068577, 0.270250256365875, 0.267216518343561, 0.264195763997261,
    0.261187919132721, 0.258192911337619, 0.255210669954662, 0.252241126055942,
    0.249284212418529, 0.246339863501264, 0.24340801542275, 0.240488605940501,
    0.237581574431238, 0.23468686187233, 0.231804410824339, 0.228934165414681,
    0.226076071322381, 0.223230075763918, 0.220396127480152, 0.217574176724331,
    0.214764175251174, 0.211966076307031, 0.209179834621125, 0.206405406397881,
    0.203642749310335, 0.200891822494657, 0.198152586545776, 0.195425003514135,
    0.192709036903589, 0.190004651670465, 0.187311814223801, 0.1846304924268,
    0.181960655599523, 0.179302274522848, 0.176655321443735, 0.174019770081839,
    0.171395595637506, 0.168782774801212, 0.166181285764482, 0.163591108232366,
    0.161012223437511, 0.158444614155925, 0.15588826472448, 0.153343161060263,
    0.150809290681846, 0.148286642732575, 0.145775208005994, 0.143274978973514,
    0.140785949814445, 0.138308116448551, 0.135841476571254, 0.133386029691669,
    0.130941777173644, 0.12850872228, 0.126086870220186, 0.123676228201597,
    0.12127680548479, 0.11888861344291, 0.116511665625611, 0.114145977827839,
    0.111791568163838, 0.109448457146812, 0.107116667774684, 0.104796225622487,
    0.102487158941935, 0.10018949876881, 0.0979032790388625, 0.095628536713009,
    0.093365311912691, 0.0911136480663738, 0.0888735920682759,
    0.0866451944505581, 0.0844285095703535, 0.082223595813203,
    0.0800305158146631, 0.0778493367020961, 0.0756801303589272,
    0.0735229737139814, 0.0713779490588905, 0.0692451443970068,
    0.0671246538277886, 0.065016577971243, 0.0629210244377582, 0.06083810834954,
    0.0587679529209339, 0.0567106901062031, 0.0546664613248891,
    0.0526354182767924, 0.0506177238609479, 0.0486135532158687,
    0.0466230949019305, 0.0446465522512946, 0.0426841449164746,
    0.0407361106559411, 0.0388027074045262, 0.0368842156885674,
    0.0349809414617162, 0.0330932194585786, 0.0312214171919203,
    0.0293659397581334, 0.0275272356696031, 0.0257058040085489,
    0.0239022033057959, 0.0221170627073089, 0.0203510962300445,
    0.0186051212757247, 0.0168800831525432, 0.0151770883079353,
    0.0134974506017399, 0.0118427578579079, 0.0102149714397015,
    0.00861658276939875, 0.00705087547137324, 0.00552240329925101,
    0.00403797259336304, 0.00260907274610216, 0.0012602859304986,
    0.000477467764609386 };

  real_T x;
  do {
    exitg1 = 0;
    genrand_uint32_vector(state, u32);
    i = (int32_T)((u32[1] >> 24U) + 1U);
    r = (((real_T)(u32[0] >> 3U) * 1.6777216E+7 + (real_T)((int32_T)u32[1] &
           16777215)) * 2.2204460492503131E-16 - 1.0) * dv0[i];
    if (fabs(r) <= dv0[i - 1]) {
      exitg1 = 1;
    } else if (i < 256) {
      u = genrandu(state);
      if (dv1[i] + u * (dv1[i - 1] - dv1[i]) < exp(-0.5 * r * r)) {
        exitg1 = 1;
      }
    } else {
      do {
        u = genrandu(state);
        x = log(u) * 0.273661237329758;
        u = genrandu(state);
      } while (!(-2.0 * log(u) > x * x));

      if (r < 0.0) {
        r = x - 3.65415288536101;
      } else {
        r = 3.65415288536101 - x;
      }

      exitg1 = 1;
    }
  } while (exitg1 == 0);

  return r;
}

static void genrand_uint32_vector(uint32_T mt[625], uint32_T u[2])
{
  int32_T i;
  uint32_T mti;
  int32_T kk;
  uint32_T y;
  uint32_T b_y;
  uint32_T c_y;
  uint32_T d_y;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    u[i] = 0U;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    mti = mt[624] + 1U;
    if (mti >= 625U) {
      for (kk = 0; kk < 227; kk++) {
        y = (mt[kk] & 2147483648U) | (mt[1 + kk] & 2147483647U);
        if ((int32_T)(y & 1U) == 0) {
          b_y = y >> 1U;
        } else {
          b_y = y >> 1U ^ 2567483615U;
        }

        mt[kk] = mt[397 + kk] ^ b_y;
      }

      for (kk = 0; kk < 396; kk++) {
        y = (mt[227 + kk] & 2147483648U) | (mt[228 + kk] & 2147483647U);
        if ((int32_T)(y & 1U) == 0) {
          c_y = y >> 1U;
        } else {
          c_y = y >> 1U ^ 2567483615U;
        }

        mt[227 + kk] = mt[kk] ^ c_y;
      }

      y = (mt[623] & 2147483648U) | (mt[0] & 2147483647U);
      if ((int32_T)(y & 1U) == 0) {
        d_y = y >> 1U;
      } else {
        d_y = y >> 1U ^ 2567483615U;
      }

      mt[623] = mt[396] ^ d_y;
      mti = 1U;
    }

    y = mt[(int32_T)mti - 1];
    mt[624] = mti;
    y ^= y >> 11U;
    y ^= y << 7U & 2636928640U;
    y ^= y << 15U & 4022730752U;
    y ^= y >> 18U;
    u[i] = y;
  }
}

static real_T genrandu(uint32_T mt[625])
{
  real_T r;
  int32_T exitg1;
  uint32_T u[2];
  boolean_T isvalid;
  int32_T k;
  boolean_T exitg2;
  uint32_T b_r;

  /* <LEGAL>   This is a uniform (0,1) pseudorandom number generator based on: */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>    A C-program for MT19937, with initialization improved 2002/1/26. */
  /* <LEGAL>    Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto. */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>    Copyright (C) 1997 - 2002, Makoto Matsumoto and Takuji Nishimura, */
  /* <LEGAL>    All rights reserved. */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>    Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without */
  /* <LEGAL>    modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions */
  /* <LEGAL>    are met: */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>      1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright */
  /* <LEGAL>         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>      2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright */
  /* <LEGAL>         notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the */
  /* <LEGAL>         documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>      3. The names of its contributors may not be used to endorse or promote */
  /* <LEGAL>         products derived from this software without specific prior written */
  /* <LEGAL>         permission. */
  /* <LEGAL> */
  /* <LEGAL>    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS */
  /* <LEGAL>    "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT */
  /* <LEGAL>    LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR */
  /* <LEGAL>    A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR */
  /* <LEGAL>    CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, */
  /* <LEGAL>    EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, */
  /* <LEGAL>    PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR */
  /* <LEGAL>    PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF */
  /* <LEGAL>    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING */
  /* <LEGAL>    NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS */
  /* <LEGAL>    SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. */
  do {
    exitg1 = 0;
    genrand_uint32_vector(mt, u);
    r = 1.1102230246251565E-16 * ((real_T)(u[0] >> 5U) * 6.7108864E+7 + (real_T)
                                  (u[1] >> 6U));
    if (r == 0.0) {
      if ((mt[624] >= 1U) && (mt[624] < 625U)) {
        isvalid = TRUE;
      } else {
        isvalid = FALSE;
      }

      if (isvalid) {
        isvalid = FALSE;
        k = 1;
        exitg2 = FALSE;
        while ((exitg2 == FALSE) && (k < 625)) {
          if (mt[k - 1] == 0U) {
            k++;
          } else {
            isvalid = TRUE;
            exitg2 = TRUE;
          }
        }
      }

      if (!isvalid) {
        b_r = 5489U;
        mt[0] = 5489U;
        for (k = 0; k < 623; k++) {
          b_r = (b_r ^ b_r >> 30U) * 1812433253U + (uint32_T)(1 + k);
          mt[1 + k] = b_r;
        }

        mt[624] = 624U;
      }
    } else {
      exitg1 = 1;
    }
  } while (exitg1 == 0);

  return r;
}

real_T randn(void)
{
  if (!method_not_empty) {
    method_not_empty = TRUE;
  }

  return eml_rand_mt19937ar_stateful();
}

/* End of code generation (randn.c) */code here
```

Comment: You're going to be looking for some function which "seeds" the random number generator. Generally in C you'd use `srand(...seed value...)` once to seed the random number generator and `rand()` to get random numbers.

Comment: Could I see the Matlab code please?

Comment: It's a [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). If you want C code for the Mersenne Twister algorithm, don't use Matlab's ten-year old slow implementation. Instead, use the [Double precision SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html#dSFMT) code from the creators. It's over twice as fast in my testing. You'll still need a scheme to generate normal variate from the uniform random values (Marsaglia log-polar or Ziggurat).

Comment: Could you show me where to find code/learn about how to generate the normal distribution? I have basically no C knowledge so preferably it would be something someone like me could understand.

Comment: If you obtained this from compiling out Matlab code, then why not do the same for setting the seed? How do you do it in Matlab? `rng('shuffle')` seeds the random number generators for `rand`, `randi`, and `randn` based on the current time.

Comment: Unfortunately matlab will not allow me to translate the code into matlab if I use rng('shuffle').

Comment: Why do you need it to be different teach time? One important aspect of pseudorandom number generation is repeatability so that one can rerun experiments exactly. If you want it to be different, just set a different seed: `rng(1)` vs. `rng(0)` (do those compile?).  Why are you translating this into C if you have no C knowledge?

Comment: Also, if you relaunched Matlab each time you ran your Matlab code you'd see that, just as with your C code, you'd get the same results every time. Matlab seeds the random number generators itself at launch. Your C code either needs to take a seed as an input or stay running for subsequent iterations, similar to the Matlab environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the Matlab documentation on how to set the seed value for generating random numbers.  If I remember correctly it is a separate function that you invoke prior to generating the random numbers.  So, you in the end you might have to generate the C code for the seed function.

In Matlab you should be able to use the same seed to generate the same sequence of psuedo random numbers, so initially recreate the problem in Matlab by setting the same seed value for two random number invocations.

It has been awhile since I used Matlab and I don't have any documentation in front of me, but, IF memory serves, the `static const real_T dv0[257] =` statement defines the elements used to drive the random number generation.  I think there is a way to define where in the `dv0` vector your sequence of number begins.

Please let me know what the Matlab docs say.